# Easyjet multiple hold bags maximum weight

Tags: air-travel, luggage, fees-and-charges, easyjet

**EDIT:** All went well: it was indeed 60 kg.

I am trying figure out if EasyJet gives misleading details or I have been given incorrect information. I am moving country and I booked for 3 suitcases. I understood that each could be 20 kg, but I am told by two friends that it is untrue and instead the total weight of all suitcases is 20 kg.
On one hand my booking page clearly states that 60 kg is the weight:
[image: snapshot of my booking weight] and states that

> You can share/pool your total weight allowance across your Hold bags and Sporting items,see below for more information on what you can bring, weight allowances and terms.

and

> Each passenger (including children and infants) is entitled to bring up to 3 hold bags - these exclude any small or large sports equipment detailed below.
>   Each bag includes 20kg of weight. Excess weight can be purchased

On the other, I heard eye witness accounts (albeit dated) to the contrary, so I am trying to figure out if there is a catch. The above excerpt is within the booking management page and not within the rules and regs [website](http://www.easyjet.com/en/help/preparing-to-fly/baggage), which is a tad more equivocal, but seems to agree with my interpretation. It does explicitly say that my total maximum weight allowance is the sum of the weight of each item and one of the headers is `Can I increase my hold luggage above 20kg?` and the word "luggage" means a set of suitcases, but the text says `The minimum weight you can buy is 20kg per hold item`. So I am strongly inclined to think they are not trying to equivocate, but I am worried that two seasoned travellers warned me. Has anyone else had this?

Comment: I think you are overly worried and the rules are quite clear: 20kg per hold item times 3 hold items you purchased = 60kg. Where did you hear about the contrary?

Comment: Although I doubt that it is 'poolable'. Imagine you give them a 59 kg bag and two .4 kg each - you are still under 60, but how should they handle the 59 kg bag? They might be generous with 'around 20', but significantly more than 20 will not work, as the handling becomes too difficult/dangerous for them.

Comment: I remember that this used to be the case. e.g. http://nothing.tmtm.com/2007/03/easyjets-additional-luggage-policy/comment-page-2/ or http://blog.sendmybag.com/post/34969113617/booked-a-second-suitcase-with-easy-jet-better However, from the policy linked above, this must have changed at some point

Comment: @mts, I heard it from two first hand victims of the non-sensical policy. However, I strongly suspect it is a former policy no longer in use as discussed above.

Comment: If this weren't the case I believe they would be committing fraud because the wording is crystal clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Historically**, Easyjet's checked-luggage policy was [20kg per person](http://web.archive.org/web/20130330041531/http://www.easyjet.com/planning/baggage)

> Each passenger who pays for a hold bag can take up to 20kg of luggage.
>   This weight allowance applies to the passenger rather than to the bag
>   so **purchasing extra bags is possible but will not increase the weight
>   allowance**.

Accessing a link to the previous version of the page now redirects to the [current policy](http://www.easyjet.com/en/help/preparing-to-fly/baggage) which no longer mentions a per person or total weight limit.

I believe the confusion arises from your friends' knowledge of Easyjet's old luggage policy. Your booking clearly states that the 20kg applies per bag.

Edit: addressing an item in comments, note that you are permitted to pool your luggage allowance on EasyJet (from above policy link):

> **Can I pool my hold luggage allowance with other passengers on my
>   booking?**
>   You can pool your total luggage weight allowance – across
>   items and across customers – but an individual item cannot weigh more
>   than 32 kg.
>
> So, each passenger with two items of 20kg hold luggage has a total
>   weight allowance of 40kg. They could pool their luggage allowance by
>   bringing one bag weighing 23kg and one bag weighing 17kg.
>
> OR
>
> Two passengers on the same booking, each with one 20kg item of hold
>   luggage, have a total luggage allowance of 40kg. So they could pool
>   their combined luggage allowance by bringing one bag weighing 22kg and
>   one bag weighing 18kg.

Comment: Do take a print of the page you showed in the Q but I agree, it should be alright.